# Хочу вывести расширения всех файлов в папке при помощи FilenameUtils, но получаю вывод пустых строк

Tags: java, файлы

Нашел решение в интернете, но в итоге получаю в консоли многострочный пустой вывод.
Вот мой код:

```java
package com.mycompany.app;
    
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import java.io.File;
    
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        File file = new File("D:/GeForce Media/War Thunder");
    
        String fileName = file.getName();
    
        if(file.isDirectory())
        {
            for(File item : file.listFiles()){
    
                if(item.isDirectory()){
    
                    // System.out.println(item.getName() + "  \t folder");
                    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
                    System.out.println(extension);
                }
                else{
                    // System.out.println(item.getName() + "\t file");
                    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
                    System.out.println(extension);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Такой вывод получаю:

```
C:\Users\olehh\.jdks\corretto-18.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Users\olehh\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57426:C:\Users\olehh\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\FileOrganiser\my-app\target\classes;C:\Users\olehh\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar com.mycompany.app.App



















































































































Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: "Нашёл решение в интернете" - вы либо его сильно переделали, либо мне страшно за человека, который решил поделиться этим решением в сети. Вся эта гора иф-елсов выглядит совершенно сумасшедшим образом, особенно потому, что последние `if` и `else` выполняют одинаковую работу.

Comment: Похоже что вы нашли корректное решение, но, закомментировав рабочий код, получили вывод пустых строк (расширение начальной директории `"War Thunder"`) для _каждого_ элемента в заданной директории, см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1542933/386633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле вы каждый раз выводите расширение для переменной `fileName`, которая берет название ***начальной директории** `"D:/GeForce Media/War Thunder"`*, соответственно в `fileName` должно содержаться значение `"War Thunder"`, для которого *расширение* будет пустой строкой.

В цикле нужно было брать расширение для `item`, что собственно и было записано в закомментированном коде `// System.out.println(item.getName() + "  \t folder");`:

```java
File rootDir = new File("D:/GeForce Media/War Thunder");
String rootDirName = rootDir.getName();

if (rootDir.isDirectory()) {
    for (File item : rootDir.listFiles()) {
        String type = item.isDirectory() ? "DIR" : "FILE";
        String itemName = item.getName();
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(itemName);
        System.out.printf("%s: name=%s  extension=%s%n", type, itemName, extension);
    }
}
```